# Joining a Webex conference using Twilio api

Tags: twilio, webex

I want to join Webex conference using Twilio api. I am using Call class like this:

`Call call = Call.creator(toNum, fromNum, twiMLUrl).setSendDigits(dialCode).setStatusCallback(STATUS_CALLBACK_URL).setStatusCallbackEvent(callbackEvents).create();`

Here fromNum is my Twilio number, toNum is the phone number provided by Webex and dialCode is the participant code

I am unable to join the conference. I feel it is because webex asks to enter "1" to confirm the participant code in the end while joining.

Is there a way in api to send that "1" to confirm?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It's a little bit blunt, but you can [send pauses as part of the `sendDigits` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional). Every "w" you send as part of the string will pause for half a second.

It might take a bit of testing, but you should be able to make your `dialCode` out of the initial code, say "1234", a few pauses and then the final "1". Like `1234wwwwww1`.

Let me know if that helps at all.